# Carte Status / Kettle Slave Server Status page shows status for random runs instead of the latest run

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am trying to programmatically get the details of a specific execution of a transformation

**What I have tried so far**

I get the status of the Kettle Slave Server/Carte at

```
http://localhost:8282/kettle/status/
```

From this page, I can click on the desired transformation and I am taken to another page that shows the details and also has a link to the XML output to the current status of a specific execution of a transformation. The link is something like this:

```
http://localhost:8282/kettle/transStatus/?name=trans_name&id=Carte_Ob_ID&xml=y
```

**The problem**

I have a transformation that has been run multiple times recently. I don't have the Carte_Obj_ID for a specific run of the transformation. So, I can't provide it in the URI. If I try the following URI instead:

```
http://localhost:8282/kettle/transStatus/?name=trans_name&xml=y
```

then I get the status of a random execution. Not the latest one or any specific one.

**The Goal**

I am writing a .net GUI where I have this code.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.
                        Create(@"http://localhost:8282/kettle/transStatus/?
                                name=Trans_Name
                                &id=Carte_Obj_ID
                                &xml=y");
req.Method = "GET";
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("cluster", "cluster");                
resp = req.GetResponse();
xmlResultStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(xmlResultStream, Encoding.UTF8);
String a = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

I intend to get the status XML of a specific execution of a transformation and allow a non-Pentaho admin user to run transformations at a  click of a button.

Thanks for any help in advance. I have taken inspiration from [this article](http://www.ibridge.be/?p=199).

**Update:**

I saw [this old JIRA entry](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-7227) where this bug is said to be fixed. I have PDI 5.0 trial version, not sure if this fix is actually there.

**Update 2:**

Based on the suggestion below I am trying to run a transformation and fetch the carte object ID for that specific execution (so that I can then run other operations (like transStatus etc) based on that specific object ID).

I tried the following URI but I get an unexpected error:

```
http://localhost:8282/kettle/runTrans/?trans=
C:%2FProgram%20Files%2Fpentaho%2Fdesign-tools%2Fdata-integration%2Fsamples%2Ftransformations%2FCSV%20Input%20-%20Reading%20customer%20data%20v2.ktr
&FileName=C:%2FProgram%20Files%2Fpentaho%2Fdesign-tools%2Fdata-integration%2Fsamples%2Ftransformations%2Fcust.txt
&level=DebugLevel
&xml=y
```

What could possibly be wrong with this URI?

Note that the following works fine for me. However it doesn't give me the carte obj ID in the result:

```
http://localhost:8282/kettle/executeTrans/?trans=
C:%2FProgram%20Files%2Fpentaho%2Fdesign-tools%2Fdata-integration%2Fsamples%2Ftransformations%2FCSV%20Input%20-%20Reading%20customer%20data%20v2.ktr
&FileName=C:%2FProgram%20Files%2Fpentaho%2Fdesign-tools%2Fdata-integration%2Fsamples%2Ftransformations%2Fcust.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I see your URL command is really huge.
I think it is better to use file repository. This way you can run a job with much shorter url by only using job name / transformation name.
To use a repository with carte you will have to configure a carte xml configuration file.
Mines is called: carte-config.xml
And its content is like this:

```
<slave_config>
  <slaveserver>
    <name>My_carte_server</name>
    <hostname>192.168.0.1</hostname>
    <port>8081</port>
    <master>N</master>
    <username>cluster</username>
    <password>cluster</password>
  </slaveserver>
  <repository><name>ProjectsRepository</name><username>admin</username><password></password></repository>
</slave_config>
```

Then I can Start carte with a command like this:
 **sh carte.sh carte-config.xml**

When carte is started with my repository settings I am able to run a job like this:
**http://192.168.0.1:8081/kettle/runJob?job=job_teste_1**
Notice that I don't need to tell carte the full path for the job.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Kettle with carte to call job execution.
For example I can start a job with a url like this:
**host_ip:host_port/kettle/runJob/?job=job_name&job_param_1=123**
Then I get a XML response like this:

```
<webresult>
<result>OK</result>
<message>Job started</message>
<id>549387d0-e621-4b6f-aa63-2783a2116e7c</id>
</webresult>
```

The tag **id** provides us with the carte execution ID that we can use to check execution status like this:
**host_ip:host_port/kettle/jobStatus/?name=job_name&id=549387d0-e621-4b6f-aa63-2783a2116e7c**

or if you want xml response just add **"&xml=y"** to the url:
**host_ip:host_port/kettle/jobStatus/?name=job_name&id=549387d0-e621-4b6f-aa63-2783a2116e7c&xml=y**

Hope this helps.

Important note.
It is important to note the to start a job we can use startJob or runJob.
The difference is that startJob requires an existing job in carte server.
While runJob start a new job and is the one to be used in a carte server because if your server reboots the carte server looses all history of job/transformation IDs

Answer (score 0):

The object ID determines which execution of the transformation or job you want to see so you can't just ignore it.
The ID is provided to you as part of the result when you execute a transformation on Carte.

Comment: I am running transformations remotely via the webservice that kettle exposes: 
http://localhost:8282/kettle/executeTrans/?trans=trans_file_name

Is there a way to fetch the carte obj ID of this specific execution of a transformation? Is this present in the result somewhere?

Comment: executeTrans was designed to pass data over a web service to for example a browser.  As such, if you want to expose the ID of the transformation you have to write it yourself.  If you want to have the ID, you can have a JavaScript step write the ID or use the runTrans method (which would be easier in any case).  http://www.ibridge.be/?p=199

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question with more info now. Can you please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mattcasters - Hi Matt, I am facing the same problem here; could you be more specific about how to get hold of transformation step in JavaScript? In particular, your link shows how to get hold of Servlet Print Writer, but that _step_ variable appears out of thin air. How and where do you construct it? Thanks